# How could you get all the floats within an unformatted variable length string in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, parsing

Let's say I have a string that contains a bunch of floats like this:

```
1.00 [6.50, 1.00, 0.50; 4.00, 1.50, 3.50; ...]
```

Each float has two decimals to the right of the decimal point (because I used `snprintf` with the `%.2f` specifier. How would I extract each of these floats into a float array?

Here is what I tried to get the first three floats:

```
                const char *linkLabel = "1.00 [6.50, 1.00, 0.50; 4.00, 1.50, 3.50]"

                float arr[3];
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    sscanf(linkLabel, "%f", &arr[i]);
                    printf("%f\n", arr[i]);
                }
```

However, since there are other characters in the way (spaces, commans, brackets), and sscanf needs a fixed amount of floats in the string to extract them (you cannot extract all the floats without knowing how many there are), I am stuck on how to do it correctly.

Any help is appreciated,

Vikas

Comment: use opposite to the printf function : scanf or any of its variations.

Comment: it's two decimals to the right, after the comma

Comment: help us to help you..show what you tried already and how it failed.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh: Thank you for the suggestion. I edited.

Comment: Is the problem exclusively how to advance through the string, or is it how to expand a dynamically growing `float` array? Or both? It cuts the answer size down by half if you already have a handle on the latter.

Comment: @P__J__: I tried, but sscanf requires a format in which you know how many floats there are in the string, but in this case that info is not available.

Comment: @VikasM you can do it one at a time. Check out [how the `%n` format specifier works](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), and think about how you can use that in conjunction with a pointer to `char` that you start at the beginning of your string, then advance past any just-read `float` and manually skip whatever cruft follows. Btw, since you're building this string with `sprintf`, you can save yourself some headache by not putting the cruft in in the first place.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I have a dynamic fvector implementation already, I just need some pseudocode (doesn't have to be specific) on how to go through the string and extract each float and add to the vector (or c-style array if preferred).

Comment: @WhozCraig: Thank you. I will check out the %n specifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current implementation won't advance through the string, it simply consumes the same value over and over.

You can walk the string and consume any "next float" using `sscanf` with a combination of `%f` (read `float`) , `%n` (tell me how many characters were just consumed), and the result of the `sscanf` call to tell you whether the float was actually extracted.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "1.00 6.50, 1.00, 0.50; 4.00, 1.50, 3.50";

    float value;
    char *rp = str;
    int n = 0;
    while (*rp && sscanf(rp, "%f%n", &value, &n) == 1)
    {
        printf("read: %f\n", value);
        rp += n; // HERE. adjust next read start point

        // this just skips all decimals and non-digit characters
        // until EOS or a decimal or digit is encountered.
        while (*rp && *rp != '.' && !isdigit((unsigned char)*rp))
            ++rp;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
read: 1.000000
read: 6.500000
read: 1.000000
read: 0.500000
read: 4.000000
read: 1.500000
read: 3.500000
```

I leave storing each read value to your dynamic array as an exercise to you, but I'm sure it's obvious it's done in the loop after each successful extraction.

Comment: Thank you! The code does exactly what I need. Didn't know about the '%n' specifier till just now.